# IIS 7 and chunk/stream file upload issue

Tags: .net, iis-7, chunked

I'm trying to upload a audio file through the WCF Rest services. We have a web player who can send the data to server by chunk while recording. We have to upload the large file so have choosen the CHUNKED option here. The service's method working fine, when STOP the recording or defined recording duration is over, recoreded file saved in file system.

However, I've noticed when CHUNKED is enabled then method does not get called until the file is completely uploaded meaning its seems like WCF is caching the file somewhere before it calls the method. Instead of this behavior service method should called immediately after receving the first chunk and file should be created in the file system. We also examined the result using wireshark and found that many packets of chunk data are there but file saved only after the STOP.

Below is the service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<standardEndpoints >
<webHttpEndpoint >
<standardEndpoint
maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" transferMode="Streamed"/>
</webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

We also used
`appcmd set config /section:asp /enableChunkedEncoding:True|False` to enable or disable HTTP 1.1 `chunked` transfer encoding, but it did not work.